# SQL Select Where Opposite Match Does Not Exist

Tags: sql

Trying to compare between two columns and check if there are no records that exist with the reversal between those two columns. Other Words looking for instances where 1-> 3 exists but 3->1 does not exist. If 1->2 and 2->1 exists we will still consider 1 to be part of the results.

```
Table  = Betweens

start_id | end_id
       1 | 2
       2 | 1
       1 | 3
```

1 would be added since it is a start to an end with no opposite present of 3,1. Though it did not get added until the 3rd entry since 1 and 2 had an opposite.

So, eventually it will just return names where the reversal does not exist.

I then want to join another table where the number from the previous problem has its name installed on it.

```
Table = Names
id | name
 1 | Mars
 2 | Earth
 3 | Jupiter
```

So results will just be the names of those that don't have an opposite.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what the question is.  Is it finding the unmatched pairs?  Or is it joining to get the names?  Why would you want only one name, if two ids define the pair?  A *pair* is missing, not a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `not exists` condition:

```
select t1.start_id, t1.end_id
from the_table t1
where not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t2.end_id = t1.start_id
                    and t2.start_id = t1.end_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your data volume, so with your ask, below query will supply desired result for you in Sql Server.

```
    create table TableBetweens
(start_id  INT,
end_id INT
)
INSERT INTO TableBetweens VALUES(1,2)
INSERT INTO TableBetweens VALUES(2,1)
INSERT INTO TableBetweens VALUES(1,3)

create table TableNames
(id INT,
NAME VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO TableNames VALUES(1,'Mars')
INSERT INTO TableNames VALUES(2,'Earth')
INSERT INTO TableNames VALUES(3,'Jupiter')


SELECT * 
FROM TableNames c
WHERE c.id IN (
                SELECT nameid1.nameid 
                FROM (SELECT a.start_id, a.end_id 
                        FROM TableBetweens a
                        LEFT JOIN TableBetweens b 
                            ON CONCAT(a.start_id,a.end_id) =  CONCAT(b.end_id,b.start_id)
                        WHERE b.end_id IS NULL 
                        AND b.start_id IS NULL) filterData
                        UNPIVOT
                        (
                            nameid 
                            FOR id IN (filterData.start_id,filterData.end_id)
                        ) AS nameid1
                )
```